# MPVolumeView's slider setVolumeThumbImage:forState: not working on iOS5

Tags: ios, ios5, uislider, mpvolumeview

oI use a MPVolumeView to display a volume slider. I've customized it with

```
        [myVolumeView setVolumeThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sound_slider_knob.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myVolumeView setVolumeThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sound_slider_knob.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [myVolumeView setMaximumVolumeSliderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_player_bg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myVolumeView setMinimumVolumeSliderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_player_fg.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

everything works fine on iOS6, but on iOS5, I get this error message :

```
-[MPVolumeView setVolumeThumbImage:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c29f30
-[UIDevice identifierForVendor]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8909b30
```

And it's actually true that in MPVolumeView.h there is

```
- (void)setVolumeThumbImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

Is there any way to custom MPVolumeView in iOS 5 ?

Comment: Apple provides the MPVolumeView customization only in iOS 6. You can not use the above approach in iOS 5

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 5 and earlier you must search the subviews of the MPVolumeView for a UISlider and customize the slider.